# How to set Real VNC Server as default startup program - Lubuntu 19.10

Tags: server, lubuntu, vnc, autostart

I have installed Real VNC Server (Lubuntu 19.10) and can run it fine. But it does not autostart on reboot and the Options screen (where I presumably can to set it to autostart) requires sudo access. This is the message I get:

---

Unable to configure options for VNC Server.

This requires superuser access when running in service mode as the
changes will affect all users of this system. Either you do not have a
suitable method configured to gain superuser privileges (e.g. sudo),
you are not authorised to do this, or you supplied invalid credentials.

---

I want autostart on boot as default. And be able to disable autostart as desired.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Did you try running the configuration GUI as root from the terminal, and then use it? Or do you not have root access to the system?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install **xterm** from the repositories - this will allow VNC server to invoke sudo to give you the necessary rights.

Comment: Yes, there are a couple of ways around it. After getting to know lubuntu better I got it. The Real VNC website itself also has instructions, but I did not see them right away.

Comment: Thanks a ton - works perfect in Arch Linux as well